# Jquery not detecting window size (simple)

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, mobile

Why on earth is this not detecting the window size as larger than 1000px?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    if ($(window).width() > 1000) {
        jQuery(".buy-now-iframe").sticky({
            topSpacing: 200
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Try doing `console.log($(window).width())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the "$" selector. This will only run once on document.ready().

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log($(window).width());
    if ($(window).width() > 1000) {
        console.log("detected larger than 1000px"); 
    }
});
```

Working fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/Mb6Q7/2/

Answer (score 1):

Do you have `$` defined as something different than `jQuery`? I notice in your example you use `jQuery` everywhere and `$` on the `width()` check.

Comment: I must admit, I have no idea what I'm looking for. Cut and pasting while im doing a jQuery course next month :P

Could you express it really really simply?

Comment: As far as I know jQuery can be accesed via two variables, the first is `jQuery` and the second is `$`. The `jQuery` variable is often used to prevent conflicts if another framework uses `$`.

Comment: Got it. Being a noob. Yeh i was referencing jQuery and $ simultaneously. Bring on the lessons.